# ios iMessage app extension animated gif message

Tags: ios, objective-c, message, imessage-extension

We developed an iMessage app extension that shows stickers or emoji images. We can insert message that contains a static image .png or .jpg, however, if we insert an animated .gif image, it's not animating. We couldn't find any documentation how to do this.

Let me know if you have any thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: r u inserting .gif into Assets.xcassets file? using drag and drop?

Comment: http://jamesonquave.com/blog/creating-imessage-apps-with-xcode-8-tutorial-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

For using gif images in iMessage you need to use them in .apng(Animated PNG) format.

There are many [tutorials](https://github.com/tinify/iMessage-Panda-sticker) for the same.